# Parameters are not being passed to sms for web

Tags: android, html, parsing, url, sms

i am trying to sent the user to a prefilled message, for that I am using the Anker tag like this

```html
<a href="sms:?&body=www.google.com?parameter1=abc&parameter2=xyz">share</a>
```

On android it does not send the paraneter2. i get something like this

```
www.google.com?parameter1=abc
```

i have tried url encoding but still its the same

**Can someone help me to parse the full url in android?**

p.s it working fine on ios.